# Required hidden field validation mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

im using mvc4, I want to validate a hiddenfield to be required.

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.InternalColour , new { id = "InternalColourId" })
```

Im setting this field via jquery when clicking list items.

I've decorated the hidden field with a required attribute but cant get validation error to appear in the validationsummary?

```
 [Required]
 public int? InternalColour { get; set; }
```

Can this be done??

Thanks

Comment: Client side validation?

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan both. think your answer works. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default it will not validate the hidden fields, as the default settings says `ignore: ":hidden"`. To validate all the fields including hidden set this

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ 
    ignore: [],

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    ignore: ':hidden, [readonly=readonly]'
});
```

or

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    ignore: "#InternalColourId" 
});
```